# Origin of the banana graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, quantum-field-theory

The graph with two vertices and $n > 1$ edges connecting them has been called the "banana graph" in a number of papers. For one example, see "Feynman Motives of Banana Graphs" by Aluffi and Marcoli, *Comm. in Number Theory and Physics* (2009) 1-57. (The short title of this paper is "Banana Motives", which I find endlessly entertaining.)

Does anyone know who coined the term "banana graph"?

Comment: Not an answer to the question : in my neck of the woods, this graph is usually called a dipole. I've never heard the term banana graph.
(see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_graph)

Comment: I think the term comes from banana diagram, which seems to be used in physics since at least the first half of the 90's. Other names for the same diagram/graph seem to be basketball or sunset diagrams. The older papers are not accessible to me, so I don't know if an originator for the term is mentioned there.

Comment: actually, the sunset diagram is distinct from the banana diagram (see below)

Answer (score 8):

[image: banana diagram]

These diagrams come by different names: "banana", "water melon", "basket ball". An early reference is [M. Creutz - Feynman rules for lattice gauge theory](https://quark.phy.bnl.gov/%7Ecreutz/mypubs/pub024.pdf), Rev. Mod. Phys. 50, 561–571 (1978). A more recent reference is [S. Groote, J.G. Körner, A.A. Pivovarov - On the evaluation of sunset-type Feynman diagrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806402) (1998).

There is a long tradition of giving fanciful names to Feynman diagrams. This is the sunset diagram:

[image: sunset diagram]

Answer (score 4):

I just had lunch with Oliver Schnetz and our conversation broached the topic whether any of us ever coined a name which stuck. He mentioned to be the first one to attach the word "banana" to the banana graph. As a witness serves his unpublished paper [Calculation of the $\phi^4$ $6$-loop non-zeta transcendental](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912149)
from 1999 which deals with "$n$-banana diagrams". Later he suggested the term to Marcolli. She modified it to "banana graph" in her paper with Aluffi from 2009.

Incidentally, Oliver mentioned also that the name *sunset* diagram in [Carlo's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111753) is a misnomer. It should be *sunrise* diagram because "the sun never sets on Quantum Field Theory" (D. Broadhurst) (-:

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this answer - the "witness" that is being mentioned comes over 20 years after one of the references mentioned in the other answer.